# Freemarker: converting web content to Json object

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

in a Freemarker template I want to convert the entire web content data to a JSON object string without manually write all the structure fields.Is this possible?

Thank you very much,
Daniele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data in XML format by using the `getContent` method of  `JournalArticalLocalServiceUtil`. but you could not get in JSON format directly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended using getContent method and manually converting to JSON based on field type